# ZSum : How to debug a problem in a coding challenge?

Tags: c++

To begin this is [a question from SPOJ](https://www.spoj.com/problems/ZSUM/). I was having some doubts about it.

I would like to know, what is the problem with my approach, which used Binary Exponentiation in 2 steps, the bind function is used to remove the overflow for very large values of A and MOD, and below, is the normal Binary Exponentiation function. How could I solve it?

```
#define MOD 1000000007ll
using ll long long 
ll binAdd(ll a,ll b)
{
    ll res=0;
    while(b)
    {
        if(b&1)
            res = (res+a) %MOD;
        a = (a+a) % MOD;
        b>>=1;
    }
    return res;
}
ll binPow(ll a,ll b)
{
    a%=MOD;
    ll res=1;
    while(b)
    {
        if(b&1)
            res = binAdd(res,a);
        a = binAdd(a,a);
        b>>=1;
    }
    return res;
}

ll Z(ll n,ll k)
{
    ll s=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        s+=binPow(i,k);
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        s+=binPow(i,i);
    return s;
}
void solve(){
    ll n,k;
    while(cin >> n >> k && (n!=0 || k!=0))
        cout << ((Z(n,k) + Z(n-1,k) - 2LL*Z(n-2,k))) << endl;
}
```

```
Input : 
10 3
9 31
83 17
5 2
0 0

Expected Output:
4835897
2118762
2285275
3694

Actual Output:
1774843373
1919101650
4154173929
3694
```

Comment: Please note that your `MOD` has a couple of extra zeroes compared to the source's one. Also, the posted snippet is not a [mre].

Comment: *Any Ideas or guidance on how I could solve it* -- You already wrote a program.  This means that you must have had a plan on paper before writing a single line of code.  Thus the program you wrote should follow the plan you had.  If the program doesn't follow your plan, then you debug the code using the debugger to see where the program goes against your plan, and then make the adjustments to the program accordingly.  If you just wrote code without any plan whatsoever, and hoped that it "worked" -- well, that is not the way to write programs.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the problem statement from the page<sup>1</sup> linked by the OP (emphasis mine).

> For two given integers n and k find (Z<sub>n</sub> + Z<sub>n-1</sub> - 2Z<sub>n-2</sub>) **mod 10000007**, where Z<sub>n</sub> = S<sub>n</sub> + P<sub>n</sub> and S<sub>n</sub> = 1<sup>k</sup> + 2<sup>k</sup> + 3<sup>k</sup> + … + n<sup>k</sup> and P<sub>n</sub> = 1<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + … + n<sup>n</sup>.
> ...
> Constraints
> 1 < n < 200000000
> 0 < k < 1000000

The posted attempt has some mistakes that prevents it to produce the expected output

- `#define MOD 1000000007ll` has a typo that makes `MOD` two orders of magnitude bigger than the required modulo, which is 10'000'007.
- `using ll long long` lacks a `=` and a `;` (typoes, maybe) and even if corrected, it may be confusing.
- In `Z`, the loops have the variable `i` declared as `int`, but it goes up to `n`, which is a `long long` variable.
- The output of `solve` is the result of the formula `Z(n,k) + Z(n-1,k) - 2LL*Z(n-2,k)`, but that value (all the operations, actually) should be taken modulo `MOD`.

Once fixed, the algorithm yields the expected results<sup>2</sup>, but it's still quite inefficient.

- The (IMHO wrongly named) function `binAdd(a, b)` returns the result of `(a * b) % MOD` without performing a direct multiplication between `a` and `b`. This avoids overflowing (and UB) when `a > std::numeric_limits<long long>::max() / b` (but it still requires `std::max(a, res) <= std::numeric_limits<long long>::max() - a` at every step).
  Given the value of `MOD` (and the upper limit of `n`), a 64-bit integer type is wide enough to perform all the needed modular multiplication using the known formula `(A * B) mod C = (A mod C * B mod C) mod C` without overflowing.
  Note that this is also the reason why the loops in OP's `Z` function can accumulate all those sums without overflowing.
- There's no need to loop linearly up to `n`:

  > Z<sub>n</sub> + Z<sub>n-1</sub> - 2Z<sub>n-2</sub> = S<sub>n</sub> + S<sub>n-1</sub> - 2S<sub>n-2</sub> + P<sub>n</sub> + P<sub>n-1</sub> - 2P<sub>n-2</sub>
  > = 1<sup>k</sup> + 2<sup>k</sup> + 3<sup>k</sup> + … + (n - 2)<sup>k</sup> + (n - 1)<sup>k</sup> + n<sup>k</sup>
  > + 1<sup>k</sup> + 2<sup>k</sup> + 3<sup>k</sup> + … + (n - 2)<sup>k</sup> + (n - 1)<sup>k</sup>
  > - (1<sup>k</sup> + 2<sup>k</sup> + 3<sup>k</sup> + … + (n - 2)<sup>k</sup>) * 2
  > + 1<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + … + (n - 2)<sup>n-2</sup> + (n - 1)<sup>n-1</sup> + n<sup>n</sup>
  > + 1<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + … + (n - 2)<sup>n-2</sup> + (n - 1)<sup>n-1</sup>
  > - (1<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + … + (n - 2)<sup>n-2</sup>) * 2 =
  > = 2((n - 1)<sup>k</sup> + (n - 1)<sup>n-1</sup>) + n<sup>k</sup> + n<sup>n</sup>

This leads to an O(log(max(n,k)) algorithm<sup>3</sup>.

---

<sup>1) https://www.spoj.com/problems/ZSUM/</sup>
<sup>2) https://godbolt.org/z/8sbo7Whxd</sup>
<sup>3) https://godbolt.org/z/bnsz94cf5</sup>